# Difference between bundle & bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What is the difference between bundle and bundle install.
When I googled it ,I found many place stating that both are aliases, is it true or are there any differences.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is true. bundle and bundle install do the same thing.

See [here](https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/cli.rb): `default_task :install`