# What does `bundle` without parameters do?

Tags: ruby, bundler

What happens when you execute `bundle` without parameters in a project where `bundle install` has already been run at least once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between bundle & bundle install](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13511188/difference-between-bundle-bundle-install)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, `bundle` and `bundle install` are the same (`install` is the default task if none is given).  So it would behave like `bundle install`.

Comment: It behaves the same way. As for what it does, it may do nothing or it may install things. It depends if your environment has changed in any way.

Comment: Very true. Bottom line it just behaves like install.

Comment: How do you know that is the case? I can't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah it's not really in the docs that I know of.  If you look in the code though, it's explicitly set as the default task.